# CSS Errors on making menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

While trying to style my html with CSS i have to use an LI and i am getting trouble with it.
If the Html or js is need i will provide it asap.
The error i am getting is at the "LI"  every time
The exact error i am getting is "property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)"

```
#menu{
    list-style:none;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
    li: {
      display : block;
      border-right: 1px solid #fff;
      background: #E7E7E7;
      color: #3B3B3b;
      text-decoration:none;
      padding:0 10px;
      float:left
            padding-left:0
            position:relative
            line-height: 4.5em
            width: 10em
            text-align: center
      &:hover{
        background-color: #3d6fc3;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#4577cb,#3264b6); 
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,#4577cb,#3264b6);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#4577cb,#3264b6);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,#4577cb,#3264b6);
        background-image: linear-gradient(left,#4577cb,#3264b6);
        color:#fff;
        
      }
      ul {
        position:absolute;
      }
      a{
        color: #3B3B3B;
        text-decoration:none;
      &:hover {
          color:#fff;
        }
      }
    }
    ul {
      border-top:1px solid #fff;
      list-style:none;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
      li {
        ul {
          margin-top: -73px;
          margin-left: 170px;
        }
      }
    }
    #drop-down{
      display:none;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `li:` what is this?

Comment: `float:left` what is this? (unclosed?) Where are your `;` ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://caniuse.com/?search=linear-gradient

Comment: Closing for reason: Typo.

Comment: Is this SCSS/SASS?